# Bash if statement behavior

Tags: bash

I am missing something fundamental concerning either the bash's if construct/operators or string comparison.
Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
baseSystem="testdir1"
testme="NA"
if [ "$baseSystem"=="$testme" ]; then
    echo "In error case"
fi
if [ "$baseSystem"!="$testme" ]; then
    echo "In error case"
fi
```

I get:

```
In error case
In error case
```

So it enters each case even though they should be mututally exclusive.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest using '=' instead of '==' for POSIX conformance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bash` happens to be somewhat particular about spaces.

Add spaces around the operators:

```
if [ "$baseSystem" == "$testme" ]; then

...

if [ "$baseSystem" != "$testme" ]; then
```

The following are **not** equivalent:

```
[ "$a"="$b" ]
[ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

Your first test is essentially the same as saying `if [ "testdir1==NA" ]; then` which would always be true.